# Oracle SQL query count, group by with an innerjoin?

Tags: sql, oracle, count

Basicly I have a bunch of Cars that belong to dealers and the dealers have a group.
The dealer table has the GROUP.ID and the Group table has the group name.
A Group has multiple dealers

So I want to count how many cars each group has.

I am using this atm

```
select  
  (select GROUP_NAME from "GROUP" where "GROUP".GROUP_ID = "DEALER"."GROUP_ID" ),
  "DEALER"."GROUP_ID" as "DEALER GROUP ID",
  "DEALER"."DEALER_NAME" as "DEALER DEALER NAME",
  "CAR"."CAR_DEALER" as "CAR DEALER"         
from 
  "CAR"
INNER JOIN 
  DEALER
ON 
  "DEALER"."DEALER_NAME" ="CAR"."CAR_DEALER"
```

I tried using `group_by` and `count` but I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: I am using apex and it says ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: The code atm works fine I am just wondering how to count it

Comment: maybe this article will help you. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00979_not_a_group_by_expression.htm I don´t get why you get this error. Because you don´t use any group functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select
  g.GROUP_NAME,
  g.GROUP_ID,
  count(*) as CAR_COUNT
from
  GROUP g
  inner join DEALER d on d.GROUP_ID = g.GROUP_ID
  inner join CAR c on c.DEALER_ID = d.DEALERID
group by
  /* Also add here all field you want to select from GROUP */
  g.GROUP_NAME,
  g.GROUPID
```